# iPod Touch 6th gen locked; need help

Tags: ipod-touch

At some point during the summer, my youngest sister took my iPod Touch to her dad's house. I just recently found out where it was and got it back. I do not remember my passcode. We have had our wifi changed a couple of times since it went missing so it has no internet connection.

When I plug it into my laptop it says I need to unlock it to use accessories but it charges just fine in a wall outlet. iTunes on my computer can't even detect it and my laptop doesn't even show it as connected under my devices.

Ideally, I want to be able to access my iPod's photos, i.e. high school graduation and whatnot, photos I never really made a backup of and I now regret. I would love to get them back if at all possible. If it's not, is there a way to reboot my iPod touch or is it just bricked until I miraculously enter the correct 4-digit passcode?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember the passcode.
There are ways to get the device back if you don't remember it, but not with the data still intact. Apple will unlock it if you take it to them with proof of ownership, or you can put it in Recovery Mode yourself - https://support.apple.com/HT204306 - but it will be wiped in the process.